# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - determine actual error?

Tags: java, invocationtargetexception

I'm using Method.invoke() to call a function in a third party jar. Sometimes I get a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException thrown. How can you figure out what the real exception was from this?

Answer (score 5):

InvocationTargetException.getCause() it uses the normal exception chaining stuff introduced in 1.4

Comment: There's also getTargetException() but the javadoc indeed suggests to use getCause() that was introduced later.